# Django multi-table inheritance and graphene

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I am trying to serve a graphql endpoint through django-graphene. I have the following models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(MainModel, related_name='bases')
    base_info = models.CharField(...)

class ChildModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

`MainModel` being my central data model. There are several variants of `ChildModel`, which explains the multi-table inheritance used here.
I have been able to get things to work with this schema declaration:

```
class BaseModelType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = BaseModel

class ChildModelType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel

class MainModelType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = MainModel
```

which allows the following graphQL query:

```
{
  mainModel(id: 123) {
    id
    bases {
      id
      baseInfo
      childmodel {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'd like to flatten this the way Django understands the inheritance, so that I can query the data like this:

```
{
  mainModel(id: 123) {
    id
    bases {
      id
      baseInfo
      name        <--- this field from the child is now on the base level
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect the answer is in how I declare `ChildModelType`, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by declaring additional field and resolve method in `BaseModelType` class:

```
class BaseModelType(DjangoObjectType):
    name_from_child = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        model = BaseModel

    def resolve_name_from_child(self, info):
        # if ChildModel have ForeignKey to BaseModel
        # first_child = self.childmodel_set.first()

        # for your case with multi-table inheritance
        # ChildModel is derived from BaseModel: class ChildModel(BaseModel):
        first_child = self.childmodel

        if first_child:
            return first_child.name
        return None
```

query:

```
{
  mainModel(id: 123) {
    id
    bases {
      id
      baseInfo
      name_from_child   <--- first child name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's almost working. I had to replace `first_child = self.childmodel_set.first()` with `first_child = self.childmodel` as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance but other than that, it's great. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurentS im assumed that you have `ChildModel` class that have `ForeignKey` field to `BaseModel` without specified `related_name` parameter

Comment: @LaurentS didnt notice that your childmodel class is derived from basemodel